# Matching a cell to the closest highest value in another range

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a number on the "buildup" tab of an Excel workbook and a list of random numbers on the "OH" tab of the same workbook. I am trying to match the number on the buildup tab to the closest highest value on the `OH` tab.
I found this formula online and tweaked it to my cell references and sheet names, however it only seems to match the closest number and not highest closest number:

```
=INDEX(OH!$B$2:$B$250,MATCH(MIN(ABS(buildup!AC8-OH!$B$2:$B$250)),ABS(buildup!AC8-OH!$B$2:$B$250),0))
```

`OH` is the sheet with the list of random numbers. `buildup!AC8` is the cell reference of the number I'd like to match to the closest highest value on the `OH` tab.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array formula with the `SMALL` or `MIN` function, entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>:

Using `SMALL`:

```
=SMALL(IF(OH!$B$2:$B$250>=buildup!AC8,OH!$B$2:$B$250),1)
```

Using this you can increment to the 2nd highest, 3rd highest, etc. Based on the second parameter.  Also this will return `#NUM!` if no match is found.

Using `MIN`:

```
=MIN(IF(OH!$B$2:$B$250>=buildup!AC8,OH!$B$2:$B$250))
```

As @Byron pointed out, this **will return 0** when there is no large number to match, so `SMALL` might be preferred.

Comment: `SMALL` and `MIN` both ignore `FALSE` so you can drop the 3rd parameter if you want.  Saves a couple characters.  **I would be very careful with `MIN` here... it will return a value of `0` when there is no larger number to match.**  `SMALL` will return `#NUM!` which is probably more desirable.

Comment: @Byron Thanks, I forgot they both ignore false, and I didn't think about the case where the match wasn't found.